# Why WP_Query's 's'=>'keyword' searches only for 'post_title' and why not 'post_content'?

Tags: search

I have written a search query for my custom post. I am using search parameter of WP_Query for this then it has to search for both 'post_title' & 'post_content' but it is searching only for 'post_title' and not searching the 'post_content'. below is my code :

```
$institute_name = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'inistitute_name', true);
//add_filter( 'posts_where' , array($this,'posts_where' ));     this line Irritated me.
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'mypost',
     array( 's' => $keyword ),
    'meta_query' => array (
      array (
           'key' => 'inistitute_name',
           'value' => array ($institute_name),
           'compare' => 'IN'
      )
    ),
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
//remove_filter( 'posts_where',  array($this,'posts_where' ));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($the_query);
echo "</pre>";
```

If I print that result then I am getting the query like below:

```
SELECT wp_dxwe_posts.* FROM wp_dxwe_posts INNER JOIN wp_dxwe_postmeta ON 
( wp_dxwe_posts.ID = wp_dxwe_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND 
( (wp_dxwe_postmeta.meta_key = 'inistitute_name' AND 
CAST(wp_dxwe_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('ITeLearn') )) 
AND wp_dxwe_posts.post_type = 'mypost' AND ((wp_dxwe_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND 
post_title LIKE '%launch%' GROUP BY wp_dxwe_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_dxwe_posts.post_date DESC
```

As I said it is working fine for only 'post_title' but sometimes not working, it is not always working. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong in this code? Thanks in advance.

Update: below is the 'post_where' method I found in the same file. I think Either its better to remove this method or don't call the 'posts_where' method by 'add_filter' method. Finally, I got the solution by commenting the 'add_filter' & 'remove_filter' code lines. But could u please tell me bit briefly about 'add_filter' method? will I get any problem as I commented the 'add_filter' method.? I am Updating the above code.

```
function posts_where( $where ) {

    if(isset($_GET['tewa_search'])) {
        $var=$_GET['tewa_search'];
        $where .= " AND post_title LIKE '%".$var."%'";
    }

    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Normally [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) searches in the title, the content and the excerpt of the post (@see [WP_Query::parse_search()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2122)). Can you check if there is any plugin interfering with the search? There is also the `posts_search` filter, which is applied to the search part of the query string.

Comment: Because your search argument `s` should be an immediate index of `$args`, whereas you've put it in a nested array - I can't see how it works at all at the moment, unless you're doing something in your `posts_where` method to reimplement the argument?

Comment: Looks like there is a method in the same class that is called `posts_where`. Could you paste this method into your question please to help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_Query`'s `s` parameter in it's `arguments` IS used to search the `post_content` too.

There must be something that is altering this behaviour.

Looks like there's a method inside your class that is altering the query: `posts_where`.

Or maybe it's that you've put the `s` argument into an array of it's own, rather than being part of the `$args` array itself.

The posts_where filter allows you to edit the SQL search query, before it is sent. Removing that code shouldn't 'break' your code, but will probably produce different results.

Comment: Yes bro You r right I found 'posts_where' method in the same file itself. I am updating the code above. can u please check it once.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I just commented the 'add_filter' method. could you please briefly tell me what is the importance of 'add_filter' method?

Comment: Answer edited last paragraph